# Catching all exceptions in Android NDK

Tags: exception, android-ndk

I'm learning how to catch and handle exceptions in Android NDK. 
My first test was to catch all exceptions, for it I've tried a simple division by zero, but the app crashes due to it, which I thought the try and catch would intercept.

```
try
{
    int test = 1 / 0;
}
catch(...)
{
   // Error catched
}
```

Comment: You should ask a question... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Division by zero is not a C++ exception, it's a CPU-level one. On Android, those are propagated to user code as signals. Read up on catching and processing those.

Comment: Note that, on many Android devices, the CPU lacks a hardware integer divide instruction.  So it's actually a bit of code in libgcc.a that explicitly throws a SIGFPE.